# Case collision with flex-wrap: wrap when increasing width onHover

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have a funny problem that maybe somebody already had, I have a list using display:flex and flex-wrap: wrap. This also works fine, my problem is that onHover of a li I set on the right of the li an icon to visible, thus the width of the li increases and the li is moved below because of lack of space and the wrapping flag. All good so far, but I also hide the icon in onmouseleave so the space decreases again and the li jumps backs, so this all gets crazy if you can imagine it. The code below reproduces the problem, at least on my monitor and crhome, hovering on the last li.

```js
var ul = document.getElementById("fileList");
let listItem = document.createElement("li");
listItem.setAttribute('id', "li");
listItem.textContent = "Crazy jumping";
listItem.onmouseover = function (event) {  
  let removeIcon = document.getElementById("remove");
  removeIcon.setAttribute('class', 'removeIconVisible');
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
};

listItem.onmouseleave = function () {
  let idTemp = listItem.getAttribute("id");
  let id = idTemp.slice(2, idTemp.length);
  let removeIcon = document.getElementById("remove" + id);
  removeIcon.setAttribute('class', 'removeIcon');
  return false; // Prevents propagation of the event to the parents.
};

let removeButton = document.createElement('img');
removeButton.setAttribute('id', "remove");
removeButton.setAttribute('src', "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAARElEQVR42mNgGAVUAApAfB+I/6Ph+1A5ssB/MvHgsYAugOauH7Vg1IJRC0YtIAI8IsHwR+RY4AHEj4kw/DFU7SggDwAAyTHHV/YXjncAAAAASUVORK5CYII=");
removeButton.setAttribute('class', 'removeIcon');
listItem.appendChild(removeButton);
ul.appendChild(listItem);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
   display: flex;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            background-color: gold;
            float: left;
            padding: 8px;
            margin-right: 8px;
            margin-bottom: 8px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            align-items: center;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.removeIcon {
    display: none;
    visibility: collapse;
}

.removeIconVisible {
    display: flex;
    visibility: visible;
}
        
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul class="fileList" id="fileList">
  <li>
    <span class="text">Home</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="text">Home2</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="text">Home3</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="text">Home4</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="text">Home5</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="text">Home6Bigger</span>
  </li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it would be good to *see* it rather than *imagine* it ;)

Comment: It would be useful if you'd add all your code (html, js) in the example

Comment: That's not possible as I build all dynamically with JS.

Comment: so it won't be possible for us to help you then ..

Comment: You could add a static copy of the build code right? Or at least a screenshot to illustrate the problem?

Comment: I updated the code, please try hovering on the last item, at least on my monitor it happens in chrome.

Comment: @Temani Afif not always is a demo needed, if somebody already had experience with some topics you rather'd be able to understand the problem.

Comment: not everyone will understand what you described that's why a demo is needed. Code is a universal langage and we will all see the same when a demo is provided and we will understand the same .. and looking at your code right now, I didn't image it like that ;)

Comment: and now since we see the issue and since you already know what is causing this, what is your question?

Comment: @Temani Afif off-topic but with that argumentation it would not be possible to answer questions related to other programming languages where a demo is not possible to be posted here, which is not the case as you can see.

Comment: @Temani Afif how to solve this?

Comment: I never said it's off topic, I simply said we need to see this because it's hard to imagine and to provide a solution. Not all the question need a demo (I know this) but for this one we will need it for two reasons: (1) to clearly see the issue (2) to provide a solution based on your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is simply not enough space for the item to have an image (without wrapping). The "crazy jumping" is not so crazy if you think about it:

1. you hover and `onmouseover` is fired
2. the image is added and the list item wraps
3. because lack of space this triggers `onmouseleave` event (mouse is not hovering anymore)
4. the image is removed and item moves back in place
5. and over and over ...

To prevent the items from wrapping remove `flex-wrap: wrap;` from the list. But this could mean the items do not fit the container.

Alternatively you could always reserve the space for the image. Meaning you always render the image, hide it by default and show it on hover. Example below uses CSS hover to show/hide the image:

```js
let ul = document.getElementById("fileList");

// Create new list item
let listItem = document.createElement("li");
listItem.textContent = "Crazy jumping";

// Create remove icon
let removeIcon = document.createElement("img");
removeIcon.classList.add("removeIcon");
removeIcon.setAttribute("id", "remove");
removeIcon.setAttribute("src", "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAARElEQVR42mNgGAVUAApAfB+I/6Ph+1A5ssB/MvHgsYAugOauH7Vg1IJRC0YtIAI8IsHwR+RY4AHEj4kw/DFU7SggDwAAyTHHV/YXjncAAAAASUVORK5CYII=");

// Append items
listItem.appendChild(removeIcon);
ul.appendChild(listItem);
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: gold;
  float: left;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

li:hover .removeIcon {
  visibility: visible;
}

.removeIcon {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<ul class="fileList" id="fileList">
  <li>
    <span class="text">Home</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="text">Home2</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="text">Home3</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="text">Home4</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="text">Home5</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="text">Home6Bigger</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Edit:**

> It does not seem to ilogical to say "while when mouse if on the item don't wrap, just overflow" or something like that.

Like i said before, remove `flex-wrap: wrap` from the list to prevent it from wrapping. You can also prevent the text from wrapping by adding `white-space: nowrap` (see example below).

> Wouldn't it be possible to set a property in onmouseover? The question
>   would also be what property?

**I recommend using CSS for styling instead of JavaScript where possible, e.g. for hiding on hover etc. (like example above).**
But of course you can use the `onmouseover` and `onmouseleave` events to toggle the `removeIconVisible` class:

```js
let ul = document.getElementById("fileList");

// Create new list item
let listItem = document.createElement("li");
listItem.textContent = "Crazy jumping";

// Create remove icon
let removeIcon = document.createElement("img");
removeIcon.classList.add("removeIcon");
removeIcon.setAttribute("id", "remove");
removeIcon.setAttribute("src", "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAARElEQVR42mNgGAVUAApAfB+I/6Ph+1A5ssB/MvHgsYAugOauH7Vg1IJRC0YtIAI8IsHwR+RY4AHEj4kw/DFU7SggDwAAyTHHV/YXjncAAAAASUVORK5CYII=");

listItem.onmouseover = function () {  
  removeIcon.classList.add("removeIconVisible");
};

listItem.onmouseleave = function () {
  removeIcon.classList.remove("removeIconVisible");
};

// Append items
listItem.appendChild(removeIcon);
ul.appendChild(listItem);
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /*flex-wrap: wrap;*/
  white-space: nowrap;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: gold;
  float: left;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.removeIcon {
  display: none;
  visibility: collapse;
}

.removeIconVisible {
  display: flex;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<ul class="fileList" id="fileList">
  <li>
    <span class="text">Home</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="text">Home2</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="text">Home3</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="text">Home4</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="text">Home5</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="text">Home6Bigger</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Alternative**

You could also position the icon absolute, placing it over (masking) the text on hover. This will prevent the item from wrapping and overflowing.

```
li {
  position: relative;
}

li:hover .removeIcon {
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, wouldn't it be possible to set a property in onmouseover? The question would also be what property? It does not seem to ilogical to say "while when mouse if on the item don't wrap, just overflow" or something like that.

Comment: I've updated the answer. I recommend using CSS for styling instead of JavaScript where possible, e.g. for hiding things on hover etc.

Comment: "Like i said before, remove flex-wrap: wrap from the list to prevent it from wrapping. " But I need the wrapping, my list gets filled dynamically, so it could become really long. About text wrapping I don't know what you mean in this context.

Comment: So you want them to wrap, but prevent them from wrapping on hover? I don't know what other options there are, I think it's either reserving the space for the icon (first example) or positioning the icon absolute inside (or outside) the item; added alternative snippet in my answer.